# How center div rispect n-rows in Bootstrap 3?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like center a div rispect n-row in bootstrap (each row is a button) and when the view will be small the div must position under the rispect row (button). So for example: button1 ---> "hello world", button2 --->"Hi there". When I press the button appear the rispective content in the center and when the view is small the content must appeart under the button. I don't want know how made the appear/disappear div, I would like to know how can I obtain the  position in bootstrap. The image clarify the question. Here my attempt: https://jsfiddle.net/vo1npqdx/828/

```
  <div class="container-fluid" style="border: 3px solid yellow;">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
        <a class="btn btn-lg btn-default" role="button">Button1</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-9" style="border: 3px solid red;">
      <div class="uno" style="border: 3px solid green;">
             <h3>Hello world</h3>

          </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
        <a class="btn btn-lg btn-default" role="button">Button2</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-9" style="border: 3px solid red; display: none;">
      <div class="uno" style="border: 3px solid green;">
             <h3>Hi there</h3>

          </div>
    </div>
    </div>
     <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
        <a class="btn btn-lg btn-default" role="button">Button3</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-9" style="border: 3px solid red; display: none;">
      <div class="uno" style="border: 3px solid green;">
             <h3>Hi there3</h3>

          </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

as you can see from fiddle the "hello world" isn't center rispect the 3 row but if you change the windows size the div go under button1 (same if you try with the other content by delete "display:none").
[image]

Comment: If I am to understand the question, you want the text centered, or the text and the content centered?

Comment: on small view everything must be centred (content, div and buttons). On large view the div must centered rispect the n-buttons and the content inside the div also will needs to centred rispect the div. I was also albe to obtain the div center rispect the n-buttons but when the view become small the div not appear under the rispective button but to the end of all buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what OP is asking for, you'll need to run media queries.

Using the below you can do the following. Using `margin: 0 auto;` on the div containers will center them. Using `text-align: center;` will align `a` tagged buttons. As for your content, you also will end up using `text-align: center;` to center those as well. But if you need it centered directly in the box, this is a little more tricky.

To center align the content within a div, both vertically and horizontally, and allow it to by dynamic, meaning your content will decide where it is, instead of using padding, you can do the following:

```
.uno { position: relative; width: 100%; /*or whatever width you want*/ background: grey; height: 300px;}
.uno p { display: block; width: auto; position: absolute; left: 50%; top: 50%; transform: translate( -50%, -50%); }
```

With `.uno` you're setting the block to be `position: relative;`, which will allow and `position: absolute;` items within it, to only decide it's location relative to the parent container. With that, I am setting the content, or the text to be 50% from the left, and 50% from the top, and then scaling it back by 50% of those totals. [Here is a codepen of the example](https://codepen.io/ishio/pen/ZKVerJ)

Comment: Onestly I don't understand. To align content inside div it's simple because I can add style:"text-align: center;" to each content-div (except for buttons). Still I don't understand how center the div rispect n-rows on large view in my example. You give me an example wherein I have only a div and this isn't my problem.

Comment: I was giving you examples on how to do it. Check the codepen again. I went ahead and almost exactly mocked up your drawing.

Comment: If you check your code on large view the div isn't centered rispect the three buttons. The other big problem (always in large view ) is that the height of the div is connect to the distance between buttons and I don't want I distance between buttons (in large view click one button--->appear the div but when apper I don't want space between buttons). Your example works good ONLY in small device (also my code works in small device...the different is just center content so you have solved only one problem)

Comment: Then I am not sure what you are asking for. I don't seem to understand it. You drew out what you were looking for, and I imitated it. What you're looking for further extends into Javascript and isn't limited to HTML and CSS, nor just Bootstrap. I will be removing my codepen since it does not meet your specifications.

Comment: Your code works fine for small devide and resolve one of my problem. I re-upload the image of my question. Check the "wide display", I already made with Jquery appear/disapper div when a button is pressed but the problem is the position of where appear the div and the space from buttons. In your code (refer to large display) when you click one button appear the div... if you check on the left you will see that it appear a big space between first button and second one and I don't want it in large view.

Comment: Then you use CSS to remove the margins.

Comment: the distance between button1 and button2 dipend on the div height this is the problem, I try to set margin:0; to the col of buttons but nothing happens.

Comment: Look into using [Bootstrap's Tab system](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs). This has the content in a separate div and the buttons in one div. However, this will not give you your mobile alignment. You may just need to use javascript and append the element, either inside the button div on mobile, or in a separate div above mobile. Conversely, you can twist my solution by setting the container to position absolute and calculating the center of the div, or wherever you need it to go.

Comment: I try with this other way...I solved on large view but in small view the div position is wrong because is under all buttons https://jsfiddle.net/vo1npqdx/830/

Comment: Yes, as I stated, you would need to turn to Javascript and use the .append() to move the content.

Comment: Refer to this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vo1npqdx/834/  how can I center horizontal and vertical the div "uno" rispect the four buttons?

Comment: Again, use the content in my original answer. I have updated your jsfiddle. Also, do not use `row` for the buttons to remove the margins.